# how to retrive stored scala mutable Set from ElasticSearch

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, scala-2.11

hi i am stroing one id field and one Scala mutable Set in elastic search like this way

```
var genreIdSet = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]()
genreIdSet+=1
genreIdSet+=2
genreIdSet+=3

bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("testdb","test","123")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                   .startObject()
                       .field("uuid","123")
                       .field("GenreIdSet",genreIdSet)
                   .endObject()    
        )
)
```

Now i want to retrieve this document here is the code

```
val get=client.prepareGet("testdb","test","123")
        .setOperationThreaded(false)
        .setFields("uuid","GenreIdSet")
        .execute()
        .actionGet()

    id=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
    var a=get.getField("GenreIdSet").getValue.toString
```

and i am getting the following output

```
ID is 123
GenreIdSet is Set(1, 2, 3)
```

i want to traverse this Set and store its value (eg : 1 2 3) in a new scala mutable Set how can i achieve this please help me also i am new in elasticSearch and i am taking help from ElasticSearch java api .please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a scala mutable Set in elasticsearch using Array method

```
var genreIdSet = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]()
genreIdSet+=1
genreIdSet+=2
genreIdSet+=3
var xb:XContentBuilder=XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().field("uuid",artistImpl.getUuid)
      xb.startArray("GetGenreIdSet")
      for(n<-genreIdSet)
      {
          xb.value(n)  
      }
      xb.endArray()
      xb.endObject()


val bulkRequest=client.prepareBulk()
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("testdb","test","123")
        .setSource(xb)
)
```

Retrieve this array and store its values into a new scala mutable Set here is the code

```
 id=get.getField("uuid").getValue.toString().toInt
        var a=get.getField("GetGenreIdSet").getValues.toArray()
           for(number<-a)
           {
               genreIdSet+=number.toString().toInt
           }
```